# Static and responsive margin for responsive container

Tags: html, css

I have an a sidenav for my AngularJs application with a width of `75px`. I need the `margin` to be equal on the container of the content so I have added extra margin onto the left margin (which varies depending on the viewport size), to compensate for the sidenav, and given the `auto` value to the right, like so:

```
.container { width: 92.5%; margin: 0 auto 0 9.5rem; } //right auto, left 9.5rem
```

Issue is that depending on viewport size, the right margin isn't always equal to the left. I can adjust the margin so it is equal, for lets say, `992px`, but as soon as I increase/decrease the size, the right side is no longer equal and the container  visually looks unbalanced.

***Question***

What CSS property do I use to maintain an equal margin on both sides when I have to use a static value for the left margin?

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85c0pztw/)

Comment: Can you post a full snippet we can work on? Also, is not `align: center` enough to align all children as you want?

Comment: what if you put the full code so we understand well where is each component

Comment: I'll try create a fiddle. I am using components to structure my AngularJS app which has HTML in multiple templates

Comment: Added link to the fiddle

Comment: Updated it with background colours as it helps see the issue with margins

Comment: That link gves me "
Error 500

WOW! Server Error. The email has been sent to the admin.
"

Comment: Try now. I didn't fork it after I made changes

Comment: the fiddle link gives error yet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your app-container starts from the body and not from your container, you can add this, then it will be equal and not break the container

```
.app-container {
    padding: 0 1%;
    width: calc(100% - 75px);
    left: 75px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

A better solution is "the bootstrap way" (use bootstrap or something similar - all float:left, and define width in percentages)